# Android NDK/JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError With .So library

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, rtmp

I'm new to Android NDK, and I'm currently trying to build a RTMP C client for Android (and later iOS). Currently, I'm running into an issue where the application crashes as soon as I try to load my library:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
}
```

The exception I get is

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "librtmp.so.1" needed by "libtest.so"; caused by library "librtmp.so.1" not found
```

I'm honestly completely lost. `ndk-build` doesn't return any errors:

```
[armeabi] Prebuilt       : rtmp.so <= jni/rtmp/
[armeabi] Install        : rtmp.so => libs/armeabi/rtmp.so
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : test <= RTMPClient.c
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libtest.so
[armeabi] Install        : libtest.so => libs/armeabi/libtest.so
```

I've tried loading in the rtmp librarary via `System.loadLibrary("rtmp")`, but no dice.

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
LIBS_PATH := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := rtmp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := rtmp/rtmp.so
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := rtmp/
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := RTMPClient.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += rtmp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_PLATFORM:=android-19
```

My RTMPClient.c uses some structs and functions from `rtmp` like so:

`#include <rtmp/rtmp.h>`

I'm not sure where `librtmp.so.1` is coming from, but I also found it in my libtest.so with arm-linux-andrioideabi-readelf:

```
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [librtmp.so.1]
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

EDIT: I got the rtmp.so file from [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?x4cvp5hl4m9xr#qwssc54zflspa). I was sent there from [the KODI librtmp update page](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Update_librtmp)

Comment: Rename rtmp.so to librtmp.so.1 on the device?

Comment: I tried renaming it and placing it in a few different directories. I ended up fixing my issue, though, so I'll post that in just a minute.

Comment: The fact that your existing .so depended on a "librtmp.so.1" strongly suggests that it was built for a traditional Linux using versioned libraries, rather than Android which customarily does not.  Replacing this with a proper build from source targeting Android was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up throwing out my rtmp.so file, and instead grabbed the jni files from [rtmpdump-android](https://github.com/eschriek/rtmpdump-android). After putting those file in, changing my android.mk file to:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    librtmp/amf.c \
    librtmp/hashswf.c \
    librtmp/log.c \
    librtmp/parseurl.c \
    librtmp/rtmp.c

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -DNO_CRYPTO
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := librtmp

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := dump
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DRTMPDUMP_VERSION=\"v2.4\"
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := dump/rtmpdump.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../librtmp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += dump/rtmpdump.h

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := librtmp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := nelly.c nelly_tables.c RTMPClient.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += dump

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And changing my RTMPClient.c file to include `#include "librtmp/rtmp.h"` instead of `#include <rtmp/rtmp.h>`, the file compiled and ran on my device without any issues.